# Why am I encountering a memory leak when returning null and non-200 status results?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mono

In running fastcgi-mono-server4, I have encountered a memory leak with MVC 2.0 and Mono .NET 4.0 (mono 2.10.9) when returning null and non-200 status codes.  The approach i was using in my controller to return a non-200 status, which results in a nasty memory leak, is as follows.

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
Response.StatusDescription = "This is a bad request";
return null;
```

I have found that in using the following approach, I can avoid leaking memory, at least to the extent exhibited by the prior approach.

```
throw new System.Web.HttpException(404, "This is a bad request");
```

Anyone out there know the reason behind this? Is this perhaps fixed in MVC3?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that you've found a memory leak?

Comment: I can push the former code to a web server (nginx + fastcgi), hit it with a bunch of requests and watch it eventually implode. Likewise, I've pushed to the same server with just the mentioned code change, and I don't have the same memory problems. I successfully replicated both situations a handful of times.

Comment: You may try the sgen garbage collector, although it is more stable in the trunk version of mono.

Comment: Thanks, konrad.kruczynski. I am using sgen at the moment, but am not familiar with the trunk version of mono. Do you have a link?

Comment: @rposky: I do not know whether Mono's nightly builds are downloadable somewhere. You may try alpha version from here: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html or build from the sources yourself which I recommend.

Comment: I'm seeing something very similar with Web API on Windows, with standard .NET...